# Show $x+\frac{\lambda}x \geq 2\sqrt{\lambda}$ all $x,\lambda>0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> For $\lambda>0 $ and $x > 0$, 
>   $$x+\frac{\lambda}x \geq 2\sqrt{\lambda}$$

I tried to let function $g(x) =$ the difference of them and then find $g'(x) = 0$. With the given $x$, I can get the min point in $g(x)$ and find out $g(x)$ is greater than zero and finally rearrange it.

Seems not work though..

Comment: Hint. Square both sides and try to rearrange it to $(x-\lambda)^2\geq 0$.

Comment: Sorry, I have mis read the question

Comment: @TimothyLeung, use the formula $x+y\geqslant2\sqrt{xy}$.

Comment: This follows directly from AM-GM inequality .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bringing $2\sqrt{\lambda}$ to the left we get

$$x-2\sqrt{\lambda}+\frac{\lambda}{x}=(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{x}})^2\ge 0$$

So the claim is true.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, the claim is false. Now, if it were

$$\frac{x+\lambda}{\sqrt x}\ge2\sqrt\lambda\iff (x-\lambda)^2\ge 0$$

and since the right inequality is trivial we're done....**if** ....

**Edit:** What you edited in your question has a solution very close to the above one:

$$x+\frac\lambda x\ge 2\sqrt\lambda\iff x^2+2\lambda+\frac{\lambda^2}{x^2}\ge4\lambda\iff\left(x-\frac\lambda{x}\right)^2\ge 0$$